# Using third party dependency written for angular.js

Tags: angularjs, dart, leaflet, angular-dart

I'm just starting off writing a map application and I'm considering using Angular.dart with the third party directive [Leaflet directive for AngularJS](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/).

Is it possible to do so, or does it have to be ported first to dart first?

If it is possible without porting, could you help me with a basic example just to get me started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use Angular.js directives in an Angular.dart application.

Comment: Thanks. But just to clarify, would it be possible with js interop? (Not that I'd do that...)

Comment: The only way to make this work is to have an Angular.dart and a Angular.js app at the same page where the two apps manage non-overlapping parts of the DOM.